# Insert Cell's address in VBE CodeModule

Tags: vba

I try to insert a cell's address into an other module. The Procedure already works, but VBE does not like the text I try to insert.

```
INSERT_THIS = "Set W10 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TheSheet").Range("G50:G52")"
```

It says "end of statement" and selects "TheSheet". How can I mark it like a text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape quotation marks within a string. replace " with "" inside the string.

Comment: If this answer helped you please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).  Accepting an answer rewards the contributor and helps others to find a working solution.